# Pros and Cons of function-level scope (Specifically in Javascript)

Tags: javascript

What are the pros and cons of function-level scope specifically in Javascript compared to block-level scope in languages like Java?

I would like to see examples of function-level scope usage that would be harder or impossible to implement using block-level scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example that comes to mind is: JavaScript's handling of [closures](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) would be much more expensive if implemented with block-level scope.

When you enter a function in JavaScript, an object is allocated (well, a couple, but we'll focus on one) that ends up being the "variable object" — that is, where all the arguments and local vars for that function call are held (as properties). It's this object that the closure actually uses (not just the "symbols" it appears to use; that's a common misconception). These objects are strung together in a chain, called the *scope chain*, which is used for resolving unqualified symbols.

Imagine how much more expensive that would be if every block introduced new scope.

Comment: You mean if implemented with **block** level scope.

Comment: @Peter: Crikey, now there's a slip of the fingers...  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to see examples of function-level scope usage that would be harder or impossible to implement using block-level scope.

Maybe it will sound obvious, but you can implement recursion in function-level scope, which can be often useful, for example:

```
var x = 5; // global scope

(function (y) { // y - locally scoped variable on each execution
  y && arguments.callee(--y); // recursion!
  console.log(y);
})(x);
```

That is mostly impossible to implement with block-level scope.

In the above example the function will initially be executed passing the value of the outer `x` variable to it, before the function is invoked a new execution context is setup, that initializes a new lexical scope, where the `y` formal parameter is bound to it.

After that, the function expression is executed again -if `y` is not `0`- initializing on each execution a completely new lexical scope.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing you cannot do - it is not hard to simulate function level scope with block level scope or vice versa.

Conditional function declarations would be more awkward though:

```
if (console && console.log) {
    function debug(msg) { console.log(msg); }
} else {
    function debug(msg) { alert(msg); }
}
debug('foo'); // does not work with block scope
```

Comment: That actually was never standardized, it will work *only* in Mozilla implementations, because they define a Function Statement, thing that doesn't exist on the ECMAScript specification. Other implementations will simply take the last `FunctionDeclaration` although the code *should* cause a `SyntaxError` because there is no grammar production that can accept FD's inside blocks.

Comment: @CMS: Indeed. Tgr: You should use function expressions to assign functions conditionally. See http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl

Comment: @CMS: *"...because there is no grammar production that can accept FD's inside blocks."* Wow, that part I did not know. I knew that the `FunctionDeclaration` would be processed regardless of where it was inside the function (e.g., not conditionally), but I didn't realize that the grammar didn't support it. As you indicate, bad idea regardless, of course. As Marcel said, use a function expression (and as Marcel's excellent link to kangax's article points out, unless you want [IE/JScript problems](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html), an anonymous one).

Comment: @T.J., yes there are some *unofficial syntactic extensions* supported by a large number of implementations, another example, the literals: `08` or `09`, they are *not* valid `NumericLiteral`, because a `DecimalIntegerLiteral` cannot start with `0` (unless of course the `0` value itself), and they don't match with the `OctalIntegerLiteral` grammar: `0 OctalDigit`, because obviously, an octal digit can be only one of `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6` and `7`. Those literals should cause a `SyntaxError` but turns out that in all implementations the leading zero is simply ignored, `08 == 8`, `09 == 9`.